# Package management on an air gapped machine?

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum

I'm working on an ***air gapped*** Fedora 20 (x64) machine. Its air gapped because of a source code review, and the company that owns the sources does not want the machine on the Internet.

I'm trying to invoke some commands (like `emacs` and `cmake`) but they are missing. In addition, they appear to be missing from the LiveCD.

Looking at the [Yum man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html), it appears there is an option to perform a download only in the background. But its not clear to me how to specify a a particular repo (like f20-x86_64), and how to include dependencies with them.

Is there a `yum` command that I can execute on another machine to fetch both the missing commands and their dependencies?

How does one handle missing packages in this case?

Comment: Usually one downloads the packages onto a USB,CD, or etc and plugs that into the air gaped unit. I only know the SuSE distro direct download link.

Comment: *"Usually one downloads the packages ..."* - perfect, thanks. How does one do that? Suppose I go to another Fedora machine (so I have `yum`), what is the process?

Comment: Use yum deplist and next download all dependencies. It can involve some scripting...

Comment: Really after downloading, You possible want build own repository from it by repo_manager and write it to portable storage.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum deplist` and next download all dependencies. It can involve some scripting.

I dont sure `yum download` help there. I suspect it download still not installed.

Ansvers, pointing on usage yumgownload, in this qyestions can be helpful https://serverfault.com/questions/470964/yumdownloader-vs-repotrack

Really after downloading, You possible want to build own repository from it by repo_manager and write it to portable storage. Without it installing deep dependency trees be pain in ass.