# Specify Fedora version and architecture for yumdownloader

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum

This is a continuation of [Package management on an air gapped machine?](https://superuser.com/q/858217/173513).

I need to install packages on a Fedora 20, i386 system that is air gapped. I'm working from on Fedora 21, x64 workstation that has internet connectivity.

In the previous question, it was suggested to use [`yumdownloader`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader). However, I don't see how to specify Fedora 20 or i386 as arguments.

How does one specify Fedora version and/or architecture for yumdownloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yumdownloader` also takes many of the same options as `yum` does, in particular `--releasever` and `--basearch` can be specified:

```
yumdownloader --releasever=20 --basearch=i386 packages ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple cases, you can find a Fedora 20 mirror and simply download the packages you need via HTTP.  The disadvantage is that you won't have yum to resolve complex dependencies for you.

The best way, IMO, is to set up another system running Fedora 20 and use that.  Better yet, just use KVM and VirtManager to run an F20 VM on your F21 system.

One other possibility is to leverage the [Ferdora mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Mock_to_test_package_builds) facility.  Because mock is intended for cross-platform package builds, it creates multiple small chroot environments for various Red Hat/Fedora distros.  As I recall, you can chroot to any one of them and run yum or yumdownloader.